Web Service de Ecuador SRI
Eh escuchado que es posible usar un web service del SRI , y lo quiero utilizar para hacer consultas de cedulas y Ruc, pero he buscado y no tengo muy en claro como aplicar ni que url seguir, quisera un poco mas de detalles que me ayuden a realizar una api

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Realmente no existe un web service público del SRI o del Registro Civil de Ecuador para obtener esa información. En el caso del Registro Civil, tienen un servicio web, pero es de pago y requiere cumplir con una normativa específica.
Puedes encontrar más información en el siguiente enlace:
Registro Civil Web Service
Sin embargo, muchos desarrolladores recurren al web scraping en sitios que no utilizan captcha para obtener los datos, aunque es importante mencionar que, si alguien tiene suficientes conocimientos técnicos, los captchas pueden no ser un impedimento definitivo.
